# getting individual field values

Tags: 8

I'm trying to fetch each individual field of an items array. here is the image of the kint result

[image]

here is what i have tried.

1. `{{items[0].content}}` -- this one prints the whole thing in the items array.
2. `{{items[0].content['#context'].value}}` ---- does nothing
3. `{{items[0].content['#markup'].getValue()}}` ---  does nothing

Have looked for documentation, couldn't find one. Any explanation or url to documentation or example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `items[0]['content']` or if its field of type text you will find the value of the text with `items[0]['content']['#text']` or `items[0]['content']['#value']`

Comment: that does not work

Comment: i have tested with text field it works, which type of your field ?